# Anime where both boys and girls transform with their weapons

Tags: story-identification, anime, magical-items

I'm very sorry if this is vague. I barely remember much so the curiosity is the biggest thing killing me.

I just remember this old anime (nothing new, not *PreCure* type anime either) where both girls and boys (though I think it's just 2 or 3 boys? Rest girls) being able to transform with their weapons. *Hyperdimension Neptunia: The Animation* sparked it and I just can't remember that old anime but it reminded me of it. I just remember some of them transformed with cards? Some with.. guns? I hope it's not too hard to find since very little anime has a transformation sequence for both genders. I also remember that it's not very sparkly/cute if that helps. I don't think it's a "magical girl" genre like *Sailor Moon* but I honestly could be wrong at this point. It's not *Cardcaptor Sakura*.

So main points again:
Boys could and had their own transformation sequences

Mostly girls, but I remember them transforming with weapons (not into weapons, only with). I think there's guns, cards, rifles? Not sure.

It's nothing within the past 7 years. I'm thinking it might be 10+ years old? If that helps? The theme. Not sure? They were all fighting something? I don't think it was anything mech like *86*, but again I could be wrong.

Sorry for the vague info... I just remember it had really cool music and sound effects when they transformed. Hope someone knows it.

Comment: A new user has submitted an edit to this question. If that's you, and you can no longer access the account you used to post this question, please merge your new account with the previous one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). In doing so, you'll regain the ability to edit this question yourself, leave comments within this thread, and mark a correct answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Transforming with weapons makes me think *Soul Eater* off of the top of my head.

Comment: Do you remember details about the transformation? You mention they don't turn into weapons, but do their weapons change visually post transformation? Or do their outfits change in a particular way?

Comment: Digimon Tamers also had characters transform together with their Digimon into their ultimate form later on. Usually Digimon evolved through the use of cards and a card reader in Tamers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking this could be *Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha StrikerS*. It aired in 2007, so it matches the timeframe you're looking for.

> both girls and boys (though I think it's just 2 or 3 boys? Rest girls) being able to transform with their weapons.

The protagonists are all members of the Time-Space Administration Bureau (TSAB), armed with sentient weapons known as Devices. Their Devices take the form of trinkets most of the time, and transform into their weapon forms at the same time as the protagonists. I can only recall one male character - Erio - who has a transformation sequence of his own:

[image]

> I just remember some of them transformed with cards? Some with.. guns?

Sort of. One of the main characters, Teana Lanstar, has a Device that resembles a pair of cards, that transforms into a pair of magical handguns:

[image]

> I also remember that it's not very sparkly/cute if that helps. I don't think it's a "magical girl" genre like *Sailor Moon* but I honestly could be wrong at this point.

*Lyrical Nanoha* is technically part of the magical girl genre, but it's definitely not sparkly or cute. As I mentioned above, the main characters are essentially military personnel, and the battles are often quite violent and destructive.

Answer (score 1):

Top of my head that hasn't been mentioned Upotte! Upotte! has every girl being a personification of a famous firearm sort of like the console equivalent.  Otherwise, Valkyrie Drive. I only even mention the this one because of the fan service connection to Hyper Dimension Neptunia.

Again any details on how they turn into weapons will be helpful. Are they weapons that are used by others? If so Noragami? Guilty Crown? Are they made from their own blood? I think that's some boundry show.